# Gradle dependency gets excluded from EAR

Tags: gradle, assembly-resolution

I have a gradle project with several subprojects. and I have defined several dependencies in library with version numbers and aliases in the root project. Now whenever subproject needs it it can define that alias with what level it wants e.g. compile.

```
root
- build.gradle
    - libraries
        - xercesImpl: 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.1',
        - xalan: 'xalan:xalan:2.7.1',
\ project1 : ear
    - build.gradle
        - ear project('project2')
\ project2 : jar
    - build.gradle
        - compile libraries.xercesImpl
        - compile libraries.xalan
```

Since I have defined xercesImpl and xalan as dependencies of project1 and project1 is included in project2 ear those jars should be added to EAR, but it's getting excluded from EAR. I checked and transitive dependencies is not declared anywhere as false.

I have printed dependency tree with gradlew and it prints only above 2 jars as excluded others are included:

```
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate:3.1.3
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4 -> 1.1
|    |    +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.12
|    |    +--- logkit:logkit:1.0.1
|    |    +--- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:4.1.3
|    |    \--- javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.3
|    +--- ehcache:ehcache:1.1
|    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4 -> 1.1 (*)
|    +--- cglib:cglib:2.1_3
|    |    \--- asm:asm:1.5.3
|    +--- asm:asm:1.5.3
|    +--- asm:asm-attrs:1.5.3
|    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:2.1.1 -> 3.1
|    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    +--- javax.transaction:jta:1.0.1B
|    \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.6rc1 -> 2.7.6
+--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
+--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.1 (*)
+--- xalan:xalan:2.7.1 (*)
```

Comment: How do you know that these dependencies are printed as excluded? Do you also have a sample project to try it out?

Comment: Since it has * in dependency tree it gets excluded..Also i have generated EAR and it also doesn't have these jars..

Comment: Is that the whole dependency tree?